# Read a word Assign value from a file in java

Tags: java

Read a word from a file and its Assign value in java

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
      readLines("F:\\myfile.txt");
}

public static  List<String> readLines(String filename) throws IOException
{

    String word = "nameId";
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        lines.add(line);
       // if(line.contains(name)){

          //  System.out.println(line);
        word="nameId";
            if(line.indexOf(word) != -1)
            {
            System.out.println("Return Value : " + String.valueOf(line) );
             }

       // }



       // System.out.println(line);
    }

    bufferedReader.close();
    return lines;
}
```

myfile.txt contains  below lines:-

> A complete token is preceded and followed by input nameId=4456566262445454 that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of Scanner.hasNext returned true

### Below Output required

> OutPut Required : 
>   4456566262445454

Please help!!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Need to read nameId assign value i.e,4456566262445454 from my myfile.txt file

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
if(line.indexOf(word) != -1) {
    String nameId = line.replaceAll("(.*)(nameId=(\\w+))(.*)", "$3");
    System.out.println("Return Value : " + nameId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can match number with regular expression

```
String regular = "nameId=([0-9]*)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regular).matcher(line);
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```